# VBA Excel load shape with Change Picture option

Tags: excel, vba, image

I would like to create a pure shape in my worksheet, which would indicate the place where the picture should be. In other words, I would like to use the Change Picture option in Excel.
[image]

With my situation I don't have this option at all despite using `Picture` in my code, which just turns my box into cube ;)

```
  Dim locimg As Picture
  Set locimg = bow.Shapes.AddShape(msoPicture, 10, 5, 247, 317)
  With locimg
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Fill.Transparency = 0.9
   End With
```

I've prepared the box matching the relevant sections in my worksheet, but in the light of the occurrence I am unable to use "Change picture" option as only "Save as picture" is available.

Is there any way of creating the picture straight to the worksheet by using VBA instead of loading it?

**UPDATE:**

With the following code:

```
    Dim SampleImg As Picture
    SampleImg = PathName & "\Resources\Picture_template.png"

    Set locimg = bow.Shapes.AddPicture(SampleImg, msoFalse, msoCTrue, 10, 5, 247, 317)
    With locimg
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Fill.Transparency = 0.9
    End With
```

I have nothing, neither loaded image, nor error

Comment: `SampleImg` is a String, not a Picture Object. I am surprised that your code doesn't throw a type mismatch runtime error. I hope you don't use `On Error Resume Next` in your code

Comment: No, I didn't. Now I've set it globally and it started working. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not adding an image to the sheet, it's adding an Autoshape. `AddShape` expects the type of Autoshape as first parameter, and if you look closely, this type is a number. From the documentation: [list of autoshape types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoautoshapetype)

- as you can see, `msoPicture` is not among the values.

Shapes are slightly confusing, basically everything that is not stored within a cell in Excel is a Shape - Autoshapes, Images, Buttons or other controls, Charts and many more. The shape type tells what kind of shape you have, and depending on that shape type, you have different properties and methods. This is the [list of shape types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype).

So `msoPicture` is a shape type and it's value is 13, but you pass it as parameter to createShape which expects an autoshape type, and 13 is the value of `msoShapeCan` - the strange looking form (that is often used to represent a database) you see on your sheet.

AutoShapes doesn't have the possibility to contain an image, therefore the option "change picture" is not present.

You can add a picture with `worksheet.Shapes.AddPicture`, but you need to provide an image already - maybe you place a dummy image that is completely white or transparent.

```
Const dummyImage = "C:\....\dummyImg.png"
bow.Shapes.AddPicture(dummyImage, msoFalse, msoCTrue, 10, 5, 247, 317)
```

(I assume `bow` is the sheet you are working on).
You need, however, be aware that the image size/position will change when you load a different image.

An alternative could be to use an Autoshape (use `msoShapeRectangle`). You can diplay an image as Background of that shape (Format Shape -> Fill -> Picture or texture fill, then press the "Insert..." button. Advantage (or disadvantage) is that the image will be stretched if width/height ratio doesn't match the shape.

[image: Set image as background fill]

If you find this to tedious, you could think about assigning a macro to the shape that would let the user select an image:

```
Sub SelectImage()
    
    If Application.Caller = "" Then Exit Sub
    Dim sh As Shape
    Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    
    Dim filename As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Images", "*.jpg;*.png;*.gif"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        filename = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    With sh.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .UserPicture filename
        .TextureTile = msoFalse
    End With
```

Comment: Tried the first solution. Because the path to my image is defined by pathname - under the following code:  Const SampleImg = PathName & "\Resources\Picture_template.png"  I get error: Constant expression required

Comment: Const definitions can contain only constant parts - If `PathName` is defined as `Const`, it should work, else you need to define `SampleImg` as variable.

Comment: PathName was defined as String. I've changed the SampleImg to Dim SampleImg as Picture and the code started working, but I see no picture attached at all.

Comment: The OnAction for rectangle doesn't work either